# How people build their connections for the sake of publications

Tags: publications

A long time ago, I discussed this with a PhD candidate. He was honest and always shared his experience in his academic life. One of several things he has mentioned is the importance of building some connections for the sake of publications. Unfortunately, he did not elaborate on how one can make this skill. I would like to pursue my PhD, and before doing so, I need to publish some papers, at least as a second or third author, until I know how the publishing process works.

When I was conducting my Master's, which would have been the perfect time to publish, my supervisor was extremely hard to deal with concerning publications. He doesn't believe in publications for the sake of it; instead, he only publishes new and extremely fancy ideas, if there are any, or he enhances some approaches, but these enhancements also must be invaluable. I've read several papers from big names in the same field with simple yet effective ideas. This is not only me complaining about this issue, but all his students do so. Honestly, my supervisor is friendly, respectful, and has a PhD in engineering with a solid background in mathematics. However, he is meticulous about his reputation. For example, he conducts his publications without sharing or telling his students about them. I can understand that, but as a grad student, I think I have a right to know how publications are done. Unfortunately, this kind of experience is hard to pick up from books.

So my question:

**How do people conduct, share and publish their ideas based on connections they build off-campus?**

Comment: *"He doesn't believe in publications for the sake of it"* he sounds like a good advisor

Comment: @Luigi,  he is good I can say that but his PhD students publish at most one or two papers if they are lucky yet better professors than him are way tolerant and involve their students in their publications. Remember, he doesn't publish surveys which is completely acceptable.

Comment: There are often trainings offered ba the library explaining the publication process and showing submission processes. One could also ask nearby PhD students for the opportunity to look over their shoulder or assist them.

Comment: If you insist on publishing with off-campus fellows, could you please clarify your current position? Are you still in the master program?

Comment: A publication is the end product of a collaboration. You are basically asking how to find collaborators and that has been discussed on this site before. Your best bet usually is utilizing your advisor's connections to establish collaborations.

Comment: Your advisor probably was simply trying to be objective and tell you that, by the standards of your field, the content of your thesis was not innovative enough for a publication. (Don't take it as a bad thing, this is true of many thesis, depending also on the field).

Comment: You have it backwards: first produce good science **then** think about publishing it. Whether you "need" papers published is irrelevant.

Comment: At the time you are going to publish your first paper you will most likely not be the single author. So there will be others to guide you through the process. Everyone goes through this. As already said, focus on producing good science. It is not worth to publish crap just because you feel you need to publish and it will hurt your reputation. Listen your advisor. If he publishes good stuff, strife to do like him, not like the "number collectors".

Comment: What is your question? How to find collaborators? How to convince your supervisor to coauthor a paper of yours that they find premature? How to convince them to make you co-author?

Comment: @Roland, where is the link that discusses finding collaborators?

Comment: @FuzzyLeapfrog, I'm done my Master.

Comment: @skymningen, *"It is not worth to publish crap"* no one says that. People take the phrase *for the sake of publications* in a wrong direction and forgot the real question.

Comment: @CroCo Honestly, the stuff people publish "for the sake of publications" is very often not well thought through and at the end of the day crap with a catchy title.

Comment: I support the use of the word 'crap' in this context. It's not an academic term by any means, but its disparaging nature highlights the noteworthy disdain felt by the academic community to such articles. They are not likely 'crap' in the context of literature as a whole, but their expendable, commodified nature in the related disciplinary cannon makes them surplus and potentially useless.

Comment: Am I the only one suspicious of a sentence like: "He doesn't believe in publications for the sake of it; rather he only publishes new and extremely fancy ideas"?  I know of too many people who justify their lack of productivity by suggesting they only want to publish high quality work while other more productive researchers publish only "for the sake of publishing".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People who attempt to publish for the sake of it are of little credit to their field. Publishing is about giving back to your field, not taking from it. The likelihood of publication is not based on 'networking' as such, it is based on the strength of the work. If you submit a high enough quality manuscript to a journal, it will be reviewed/accepted regardless of your network. Focus on good writing and research, the rest will come.